# Multiple OSes using the same drive?

Tags: linux, windows, windows-10, dualboot

I have an SSD I'm planning to have Windows and Ubuntu installed on. Also, I'd like to have an external hard drive to store some Documents, Pictures, Videos, source code etc. Can multiple operating systems access the same external hard disk without needing to partition the drive so they can access the same files?

Comment: Yes, they can as long as the file system is recognized by both so, that means NTFS (traditionally) or exFAT. Don't forget to disable Windows Fast Startup.

Comment: In fact, there is an *advantage* to having an external drive for storage, aside from space: if you've left Windows in hibernation, that partition would not be accessible, lest *hiberfil.sys* be corrupted, but documents, photos, music, videos and other files on the external HDD *would* be fully accessible both to read and to write.